# Converting CSV to JSON omits last row?

Tags: python, json, csv

Trying to convert CSV file to a JSON file as simply as possible while adding a root node. For some reason, the JSON file omits at least the last row (in some cases as many as 4 rows) from the end of the CSV file. What's going on here?

Example CSV

```
name, id, tag
John, 12345, father
Mary, 33456, sister
Beth, 56789, daughter
```

Desired JSON

```
{"node": "", "children": [
{"name": "John", "id": 12345, "tag": "father"},
{"name": "Mary", "id": 33456, "tag": "sister"},
{"name": "Beth", "id": 56789, "tag": "daughter"}
]}
```

What I'm getting:

```
 {"node": "", "children": [
    {"name": "John", "id": 12345, "tag": "father"},
    {"name": "Mary", "id": 33456, "tag": "sister"},
    ]}
```

My code:

```
csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
jsonfile.write('{"node": "", "children": [')
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    #jsonfile.write(',\n')
jsonfile.write('] }')
```

P.S. I know I'm adding a comma on the last row of the JSON file--I'd love to also know how to add the comma after all but that last row, but that's less important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manually construct the JSON string. Make a Python data structure and then dump it into json file via [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
import json

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
data = {"node": "", "children": list(reader)}

with open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:    
    json.dump(data, jsonfile)
```

Comment: This is much tighter code--thanks for that!--but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. The final row from the csv file is still being omitted or, in some instances, replacing some values with "null" (in spite of the value appearing just fine in the CSV) and then omitting rows that follow it.